# Create Quarter from %Y-%m-%d in R?

Tags: r, date

I have `Time` in %Y-%m-%d format, how can I create `Quarter` to get:

```
Time       | Quarter
2018-01-31 | 2018 Q1
2018-02-28 | 2018 Q1
2018-03-31 | 2018 Q1
2018-04-30 | 2018 Q2
2018-05-31 | 2018 Q2
2018-06-30 | 2018 Q2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could achieve this by using lubridates `ymd` and `year` function combined with base Rs `quarters` function:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Time = ymd(Time),
         Quarter = paste(year(Time), quarters(Time)))
```

```
        Time Quarter
1 2018-01-31 2018 Q1
2 2018-02-28 2018 Q1
3 2018-03-31 2018 Q1
4 2018-04-30 2018 Q2
5 2018-05-31 2018 Q2
6 2018-06-30 2018 Q2
```

Comment: Nice and clear solution!

Answer (score 4):

The `zoo` package has a year-quarter class, so that you can have the date printed this way but it is still recognised as a time value for plotting, etc. This is otherwise lost if you convert to character.

```r
df$Quarter <- zoo::as.yearqtr(as.Date(df$Time))

df
#>         Time Quarter
#> 1 2018-01-31 2018 Q1
#> 2 2018-02-28 2018 Q1
#> 3 2018-03-31 2018 Q1
#> 4 2018-04-30 2018 Q2
#> 5 2018-05-31 2018 Q2
#> 6 2018-06-30 2018 Q2
```

Comment: `as.yearqtr(df$Time)` would work.  `as.Date` isn't needed.